# Is there a way to convert submittable/fillable PDF (containing JS) to HTML?

Tags: pdf, converters

I have a huge set of PDF files which use forms and JavaScript to submit them. I'm wondering if there's a way of converting such PDFs into HTML (or any other format *except Flash* which would allow for opening the page in a Web browser and submitting it).

After research on the topic I was able to find several pieces of software that would  convert PDF to HTML but even if there are any fields left after conversion there's no JS apparently and all the buttons are missing.

Edit: The number of documents to convert is roughly 500... so "by hand" method is out unless it's a bit of "by hand" and then in bulk

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this [PDF converter](http://www.aolor.com/pdf-converter/) will help. It can convert PDF to html, however, I'm not sure whether it will preserve your buttons and js. Maybe you can have a try. Hope this helps.